# How to fix a mechanical problem with a single key on a MBP keyboard?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, hardware

I've got a mid-2009 macbook pro that generally runs well. Unfortunately, though, I've started having problems with one key on the keyboard ('o'). It works intermittently. To type the letter I either need to press the key several times or hold it down for several seconds.

Does anyone have any pointers on how I might be able to restore function to my 'o' key?  I'd stress that I'm sure the problem is mechanical, with the hardware, not with the software. I'm wondering if there's a way to disassemble and clean the keyboard, or a way to replace part of it.  Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to replace individual keys without replacing the keyboard.

I recently replaces right SHIFT, right OPTION and several f1 - f12 keys on my 2011 13' MBP. SHIFT key was chipped on the bottom edge, which made it unaesthetic. OPTION fell off. I customized my fn keys with Karabiner, so the symbols on them no longer apply.

Mechanically, the replaceable bits come in two parts, **the cap**, which is black and covers all you can see, and **the clip**, which is white and lays underneath. The part where the cap holds onto the clip is most fragile. There are instructions about how you pop the cap. I say you should be prepared to replace a key if you decide to pop it, since, especially for first timers, removing the cap might damage the key irrevocably.

I decided to replace my own keys because 1) my machine is outside of warranty, 2) a professional would only replace the keyboard as a whole and that costs way more than buying a keyboard myself, 3) replacing a keyboard myself is a big project that requires gutting the entire machine.

I used a Chinese ecommerce site. The parts cost less than a dollar each. I'm sure you can use ebay. One big caveat is that you **should** send the seller a picture of the cap and clip you are trying to replace. Even in machines with same spec, the keyboard can be different. A fraction of a millimeter difference could mean whether a cap and clip can fit onto the existing keyboard.

Comment: Good answer. There is a nice video on youtube with some key-popping action. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kh88cn_rtLo